# What is the relationship between Activity.onConfigurationChanged() and Application.onConfigurationChanged()?

Tags: android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle, onconfigurationchanged

I notice that there are two Android methods with the same names and parameters:

- [Android.app.Activity.onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)
- [Android.app.Application.onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)

All of the documentation I can find (such as [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)) seems to refer to the method in the Activity class.  What is the relation between the two methods?  For example, if an Activity is specified in the manifest as handling configuration changes, is the Activity's onConfigurationChange method called, then the Application one, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the documentation doesn't indicate the order of the calls, you shouldn't rely on the order of the calls.

You could look at the source code for Android to determine this, but since it isn't documented it could change in the future, therefore you shouldn't rely on this.